# common authorization for all API in LoopBack 4

Tags: jwt, authorization, loopback4

In `LoopBack 4` framework, for any secured API call, I need to authenticate the request for every endpoint. Instead of this approach i wants to configure that verification globally like `LoopBack 3`. Any solution for this?

```
   @post('/users/{userId}/orders', {
    responses: {
      '200': {
        description: 'User.Order model instance',
        content: {'application/json': {schema: {'x-ts-type': Order}}},
      },
    },
  })
  @authenticate('jwt')
  @authorize({resource: 'order', scopes: ['create']})
  async createOrder(
    @param.path.string('userId') userId: string,
    @requestBody() order: Order,
  ): Promise<Order> {
    await this.userRepo.orders(userId).create(order);
  }
```

In above code `@authenticate('jwt')` was mentioned, can we mention this in a common file?

Comment: in your app constructor, what do you have in `this.api({...})`?

Comment: Did you tried adding an authenticate function in `sequence.ts`?

Comment: @salitha can you please explain how and where to add in sequence.ts

Comment: As I have no tested code, I suggest you to to refer dcumentation https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Sequence.html

Comment: I can assure you that setting annotation at the application.ts level will not enable it for all controllers. The only way to handle this is to add a base controller which has the annotation of @authenticate and all other controllers should be inherited from this.